# How to convert all values in a pandas DataFrame to string according to display settings?

Tags: pandas

How can I turn a DataFrame into DataFrame of strings according to the same rules that `str(df)` uses?

I tried `df.astype("str")` and `df.applymap(str)`, but both left floats with larger precision than indicated by `display.precision` setting.

Answer (score 1):

You can use applymap with a format string, e.g.:

```
df.applymap(lambda x: '{0:.2f}'.format(x))
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `.round()` before converting to `str`:

```
p = pd.get_option('display.precision')
df.round(p).astype(str)
```

Pandas rounds numerical data when you try to display it, to the precision specified by `display.precision`; the data is still stored by its full precision.

Directly casting to `str` results in pandas using the full precision of the float; it is independent of whatever setting you have for `display.precision`.

Comment: Thanks, this is almost what I want! But how to get trailing zeros for values with fewer digits than `display.precision`  after the period?

Comment: You'll want a `Decimal` data type for that instead. do `from decimal import Decimal`, then `.astype(Decimal)`.